# How can I properly add CakePHP's Debug Kit to a reporting tool?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, reporting, cakephp-debug-kit

I'm new to Debug Kit and spent this day with studying it, looking at its source-code, reading about it to gather as much information as possible. Even though I'm not an expert about this plugin, I think I'm ready to ask a question here on SO about it.

Documentation link: https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/4/en/index.html

While working on a group of inter-related projects, I was asked to look into ways to add a SQL debugger/logger feature hopefully along with a UI, using the model of an already existent solution at a project.

While looking into this tool, I have found out that it is CakePHP's Debug Kit, with some project-specific customizations.

Now, introducing it into the problem-space I was asked is an interesting problem, because it is a reporting problem-space which works as follows:

- the user sets up what reports are needed
- once the user completes setting up the report, finalizes it and issues the command to generate it
- the report enters a report queue
- once the report arrives to the head of the queue, it is processed
- while it is processed, potentially many SQL operations are being executed
- once the report's processing finalizes, a file is generated on the server
- the user can later visits his/her reports
- they are displayed as entries in a UI where they can be downloaded

What I would like to profile and benchmark is what happens when the report is at the head of the queue and is being processed.

Even though in this case many physical server machines and different databases may be involved, from the perspective of this question this kind of complexity is irrelevant, I'm happy to handle it. Let's simplify it and assume for the sake of simplicity that I have a reports table and each report has its own ID.

I would like to use Debug Kit as follows:

- log all MySQL commands while the report is being generated
- knowing somehow the report ID it is to be linked to
- when I load the reports page, I would like to have some button or whatever UI tool that I can use to open a dialog where the benchmarking/profiling information is being displayed
- ideally I would like to have such a UI tool for all report titles shown on the UI, if I have to implement my own UI for this purpose, then I'm happy to do so
- I would also like to add custom logs to this profiler/benchmarker, like the notification of the status of the report or that a complex operation has started/finished

My question is as follows: **Is there a way to use Debug Kit in the use-case I have described above and if so, how?**

Comment: `DebugKit` is meant as a debugging aid for developers only, and should not run in production, but what you're describing sounds like you want provide information to regular users?

Comment: @ndm this would only run while developers test the reporting. Suppose that some error happened in a long reporting stuff. At this point we need to debug the report logic. Which is arduous.

Comment: I see. And do you actually want to display anything in a DebugKit panel, or are you just trying to figure whether it provides functionality that you could reuse for your profiling/benchmarking?

Comment: @ndm it would be great if there would be an out-of-the-box UI display, but I think this would be too much to expect. I have n requests being sent to the server while the report's settings are being made and once the report's blueprint is in the report queue and eventually gets to be processed, I would have an additional set of SQL and other commands. I will need to group all these together.

Comment: @ndm so, the minimal expectation is to be able to run the profiling in the CLI environment and to be aware of what queries were executed during it. Since we are developers, we can make use of the raw data as well as long as there is a uniquely identifiable way to collect all the SQL commands executed by the process and only the SQL commands executed by the process. From here on I can also implement a UI if needed. I would not object if more is supported, but I assume that the plugin is request-based, so the logic which glues the related requests together is to be implemented by me.

Comment: @ndm the thing is that this is a huge effort in terms of research and implementation, the documentation does not provide a verdict about this use-case. So, if there is a known reason as of why this cannot be done without reimplementing a lot of the plugin's features, then I would write my own tool for this. If this is a solvable issue, then I would avoid adding too much of creativity. If not, then I would switch to plan B, the full implementation.

Comment: It's hard to tell where all the bounds of your task are, so I'm not quite sure what to recommend, but as far as DebugKit goes, it's not really made for such a task, it's pretty "stupid" so to speak, it just records data on a per-request basis, and it wouldn't know why two or more requests would somehow be related to each other. If you were to figure what request records belong to a specific report, you'd have to slip in some kind of data that would allow you to uniquely identify the records, for example via a value in the request URL.

Comment: @ndm I can implement the logic that stores records related to a report into a table. What I lack at this point is the ability to have some logs stored for non-requests, such as a CLI command to generate the report which is the head of the queue. Anything else is optional and doable. The feature I need is to have SQL logs generated while a non-request is being executed. If that's not possible, then I will need another benchmarker.

Comment: I misunderstood that, I thought you wanted to trigger the profiler from the CLI. Maybe you should just use a [**custom query logger**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/database-basics.html#query-logging), and hook it up on the fly when you need it, similar to [**how DebugKit does it**](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/blob/4.5.0/src/Panel/SqlLogPanel.php#L47-L77).

Comment: @ndm to clarify, I want to log queries both on requests and through a CLI command and then group them. The grouping is not the main problem. It is the CLI-based stuff. Yes, a custom query logger is the B-plan if the current tool cannot be used for this purpose. I'm still researching. If making it work properly through CLI is possible, then I will favor doing it. If not, then I will use a custom query logger for the CLI use-case and then group it. Excuse me if things were less clear than they should have been.

Comment: DebugKit by default only runs on web requests, it explicitly doesn't run in the CLI environment. You could run it manually (for example by utilizing `\DebugKit\Panel\SqlLogPanel` directly), but at that point I'd really just roll my own solution, especially if only SQL queries need to be logged.

Comment: @ndm I have already solved the problem using the custom query logger idea, with `$connection->fullDebug = true;` and then `$connection->getLog(true);`. If you write an answer along those lines, then I will accept it. Otherwise I will write my own answer. Thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that

```
$connection->fullDebug = true;
```

enables SQL logging and then later

```
$connection->getLog(true);
```

returns all the needed information. `$connection` needs to be an [DboSource](https://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-DboSource.html) instance.